# Is it possible to run a custom script before ng serve and before live reload/ auto reload in angular 7?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have to run a custom script before the starting the ng serve command from angular cli and before angular live reload/auto reload? Is it possible with angular 7+ other than modifying the package.json ?

Comment: How about a shell script?

Comment: @Arcteezy Will it do the job ?

Comment: Yes and No. I use scripts for automating builds, packaging libraries etc. but haven't done anything with live reload.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Find your `package.json` and add the following:
`"start": "customScript && ng serve"`.
Then use `npm run start`

Other solutions than this would be based on tricking the system and CLI.

Comment: Will it work with live reload also ? Additionally you have mentioned about another solution, can you provide more information on that may be some reference will be much helpful.

Comment: @leox https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1656 you could look at it but it is still manipulates a json file. Not the package.json but webpack.