# how to execute two servers with a single command in angular

Tags: json, angular, npm, json-server

I was working on one angular project. I was using JSON server to host the data. and to run, I use `ng serve -o`. and to run json server, I use `json-server -p 3500 db.json`. instead of using two terminals, Is there anyway I can run ng serve -o and automatically json server also starts to run?

Comment: If you work with VS Code, you can configure a launch configuration inside of `launch.json` and use the property `preLaunchTask` to execute another command before the actual `ng serve` command.

Comment: You can create a custom script in your package.json. See this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58816737/is-it-possible-to-run-a-custom-script-before-ng-serve-and-before-live-reload-au

Comment: Thanks for information Mike S . But I need to share this project to someone else. So changing in my VS code is not a solution for my problem.

Comment: You can use concurrently, like it was proposed here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30950032/how-can-i-run-multiple-npm-scripts-in-parallel